# In the react timer application component is not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state, usecallback

Can somebody spot the bug, UI is not rendering, I tried by passing  `formatTime` as a dependency to the `useEffect` but it is behaving very annoyingly.

**Observation**: It's inconsistent sometimes it works on page reload but sometimes it don't rerender the view

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let date = new Date();

  const formatTime = useCallback(() => {
    return (
      date.getHours().toString() +
      ":" +
      date.getMinutes().toString() +
      ":" +
      date.getSeconds().toString() +
      ":" +
      date.getMilliseconds().toString()
    );
  }, [date]);

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(formatTime());

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer(formatTime());
    });
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3> Timer: {timer.toString()} </h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you intentionally not passing a delay in milliseconds to `setInterval`?

Comment: Yes, I left as is to check the UI updates

Comment: Date is updating and setting the state via `formatTime()` in `useEffect`. Anyways I found a solution for it. Thank you @cbr

https://codesandbox.io/s/debounce-throttling-loqvg?file=/src/App.js:540-564